# As tags de language estão funcionando?

Tags: suporte, syntax-highlighting

Eu faço essa pergunta, porque eu estou tentando muitas vezes utilizar o `<!--language: lang-none-->`, mas não tem tido o efeito desejado. Daí a minha dúvida é se eu estou fazendo o uso correto ou se as respostas não estão reconhecendo essa tag.

Comment: Experimentou separar o `<!--` do `language`? E usar `none` no lugar de `lang-none`. Assim funciona para mim.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal: Acho que o lang-none funciona mas precisa separar os -- com espaços.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os comentários à pergunta já responderam, mas vou registrar aqui: é preciso separar com um espaço as tags de abertura e fechamento de comentário, e é preciso ter um espaço após o `language:`:

**Funciona:**

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
```

**Não funcionam:**

```
<!--language: lang-none-->
<!--language: lang-none -->
<!-- language: lang-none-->
<!-- language:lang-none -->
```